# Switch SAML binding from Post to Redirect

Tags: saml-2.0

As an SP, we've opted for the POST binding option - it seemed to be the advised approach. SAML is now set up and working with the IDP. We would now like to change to Redirect as it is better handled in Ajax calls after timeout.

My question is whether we can switch from POST to Redirect without incurring a setup change on the IDP side. Seeing as both bindings are just using the UserAgent (browser) as a transport anyway, I figured it may be possible. But the binding is defined in the AssertionConsumerService in the metadata which indicates that IDP would need to be informed and have its configuration changed.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a SAML Response (which is what is sent to an Assertion Consumer Service endpoint) via Redirect is not supported by the SAML spec since responses easily get too large to send as a query parameter. See line 420 in the SAML Web SSO Profile spec https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf

> 5. Identity Provider issues  to Service Provider In step 5, the identity provider issues a  message to be delivered by
>      the user agent to the service provider. Either the HTTP POST, or HTTP
>      Artifact binding can be used to transfer the message to the service
>      provider through the user agent. The message may indicate an error, or
>      will include (at least) an authentication assertion. The HTTP Redirect
>      binding MUST NOT be used, as the response will typically exceed the
>      URL length permitted by most user agents.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Well, it's a non-starter then. I'll have to find another way of handling SAML redirect to IDP login happening during a timed out Ajax call.

Comment: I agree on the answer, but depending what OP wants to do with his request he might get around with Artifact Binding?

See, if that gives you any clue:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SAML_2.0_Bindings

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to Artifact, though SP metadata will need to updated on the IDP to relay the changed endpoint.